# How to handle if some data in some table null, and display the non-null data if there's 2 data in the same group

Tags: mysql

i hope you have a great day!

I want to share about my problem in mysql data and solved with help of chatGPT, and i build this ask to help documentation and help the others with the same problem..

so i have 2 tables, one is table anggota_chat looks like this:

| id_anggota_chat | id_user | id_chat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123-ffx-334 | x839-def | 1234 |
| dfe-425-xxd | d238-f123 | 1456 |
| 123-fje-ke1 | Null | 1234 |

and table users look like this:

| id_user | other field.. |
| --- | --- |
| x839-def | other data |
| d238-f123 | other data |
| df23-kjef | other data |

---

## So the problem is

i need to know if some chat (in terms of group chat) doesnt have any users left in the group, and because there's some `Null` in the tabel anggota_chat, i need to list all the id_user data with group by id_chat and display it if the id_chat is fill with user data or it is not